# Comparison Operation of List Data Structure on Python

Tags: python, list, syntax, operation

Assuming that I have a List data strecture: list.
And I see one code: list[:,0]>5
I don't know what it means? But I know what list[:,0] means.

I google it and read many in python.org but I can't acquire appropriate answer.

Comment: You *"know what list[:,0] means"*? Please tell us because that is not valid python, at least not on a regular `list`. `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.

Comment: First,  ":" is a slice which is an example of start:stop:step and means all elements of list, so list[:] is list itself. Second, list[:0] means extract the first element, such as [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] => [1,4].

Comment: Not on a python `list` though. You get a `TypeError` there. Sounds like maybe you have a `DataFrame` which is something entirely different. Next time provide an [mcve].

Comment: Oh, sorry! You are right! I realized that the list is an numpy.ndarray!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realized it's a very simple thing:

`list > 5` compares every elements of list with 5, if it is larger than 5 the result is True, else False.
So if

```
list=[1,2,6]
list > 5
# -> [False, False, True].
```